# Prove that C(T) is an F-vector space of dimension ∑λmλ2, the sum being taken over all eigenvalues of T.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\textbf{Question}$: Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over some field $F$ and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a diagonalizable linear transformation on $V$ . Let $C(T)$ be the set of linear
transformations $S : V \rightarrow V$ such that $S\circ T = T \circ S$. Let $m_{\lambda}$ be the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda $ of $T$ . Prove that
$C(T)$ is an $F$-vector space of dimension $\sum_{\lambda}m{_{\lambda}}^{2}$, the sum being taken over all eigenvalues of $T$.

$\textbf{Source}$: This question from Titu Andrescu's  Linear Algebra book (page 358, prob-18). I try to solve this question, Could anyone please help, I have not idea how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot. If we prove this, then we can deduce a nice,

$\textbf{Corollary}$: Suppose that the eigenvalues of $T$ are pairwise distinct. Then
$id, T, T^{2}, \dots,  T^{n-1}$ form a basis of $C(T)$ as $F$ -vector space. This implies, if $S\circ T = T\circ S$ and the eigenvalues of $T$ are pairwise distinct, then $S$ is a polynomial of $T$.

Comment: Can you do it when there is only one eigenvalue? Can you see that if $ST=TS$ then $S$ sends each eigenspace of $T$ into itself? Do you know that if $T$ is diagonalisable then $V$ is the direct sum of its eigenspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlights:

We  note that the algebraic multiplicy of each and every eigenvalue of $\;T\;$ equals its geometric multiplicity(= dimension of the corresponding eigenspace). Let $\;V_\lambda\;$ be the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\;\lambda\;$, we then have:

$$S\in C(T)\iff ST=TS\iff \forall \text{eigenvalue}\;\lambda \;\text{and}\; \forall v\in V_\lambda, $$

$$TSv=STv=S(\lambda v)=\lambda Sv\iff Sv\in V_\lambda$$

The second double implication above follows from the fact that any vector in $\;V\;$  is a linear combination of eigenvectors of $\;T\;$ (why?)

Thus, we have characterised the elements of $\;C(T)\;$: they are the linear operators for which every eigenspace of $\;T\;$ is invariant under their action, and this means that every such operator $\;S\;$ can be seen as an operator in$\; End(V_\lambda)\;$ , and $\;\dim End(V_\lambda)=m_\lambda^2\;$ ...

Well, try now to polish  and finish the argument here.

Comment: Very nice, thanks.